Ask you why it took an hour to get to work?
I overslept this morning which I know is my own fault and I own that. I’d even accept a write up for it because it’s on me.
But I don’t live anywhere near my place of employment. On a good day it’s a 35-40 minute drive, but because I was now coming in during 8am rush hour traffic, it took me a little longer.
My supervisor emailed me after I arrived asking why it took an hour for me to get to work when I said I was on my way.
Can he legally ask me that question?

Legal questions require us to know the jurisdiction. Please add the appropriate jurisdiction tag.

Who is he ? Is he you boss ?

Yes I just realized I didn’t write that he is my direct supervisor who has an obsession with times. And yes I know jobs have time constraints but I’ve been here 6 years, he has only been here 1.5, and previously, my direct supervisors have not had an issue with being 5-8 minutes late because I always stay late to make up for it.

Did you notify your supervisor you were going to be late? You were not 5-8 minutes late. You were an hour late. Just explain you overslept. Everyone has done it.

It would seem "I hit rush hour traffic" seems to be a perfectly good answer to this question. Why not just give it?

While I won't discount the fact that the supervisor might be "obsessed" with you, the individual is your direct supervisor. At face value, when you are expected in the office and you aren't there, they are responsible for your safety. Asking where you were seems fairly harmless. It seems you have not answered my question, if you notified your boss, you would be late.

Can he legally ask me that question? - Why wouldn't it be legal? It's a benign question. How would asking you that be crossing any legal boundaries? Why not just answer with "I ran into rush hour traffic."? Why is this something that's got you worked up?

Yes as soon as I woke up, I immediately notified them and advised that I would be there as soon as possible.

As I am no lawyer so I cannot comment on the legality, but it is a reasonable question.
In fact, it would be advisable to proactively inform your manager how far you live from work.  If he wanted you to come in for an extra shift, he should know that it will take you about an hour to get there.  For me, at my current position, I live very close so if needed I can be called upon to do something at the office during my time off.
It's weird that you see this information as a violation of some sort.  I happen to know what part of town all my coworkers live as we are friendly people.
Why do you feel that it is appropriate to guard this information?

Normally a question that starts ’Can they legally...’ aren’t applicable for this site.
However, almost certainly the answer is ’yes’.

You were late.
Your boss wanted to know why you were late.
There were factors that increased your travel time, your boss wants an explanation.

I see nothing that would even come close to being illegal.
I would be interested in knowing why you are asking if it is legal...

Edit:
Okay - based on your comments, I think I have a much much clearer understanding.
To start with - I highly sympathize, At nearly every job I have had going back 10 years, I am not one for punctuality at a start time. Historically, this was because I had a minimum of a 40 minute commute, with highly variable traffic - the unwritten rule I had with my boss was that I might be up to 30 minutes ’late’ - but I usually took a half hour lunch anyway - so they got my full 8 hours.
Almost all my Managers have never had a problem with this - I would stay late if I had to.
That said
A Manager is within their rights to take issue with this.
How I would approach this is to sit down and talk with your Manager. Some people are highly focused on Punctuality and consider any form of lateness to be rudeness. This can be cultural, this can also be personal.
Now, depending on your job and the responsibilities depends on how much Wiggle room you are likely to have here:

Some jobs have time-sensitive start and finish times, I am presuming yours does not as you have mentioned that this arrangement has been fine for a number of years
Sometimes other people abuse flexi-time and this causes the spotlight to shine on everyone (which sucks)
Sometimes, despite your best argument, your Boss can turn around and say ’No, I want you at your desk logged in and ready to work at 9:00 am’ - to which your options are to comply with their request (but remember such time watching is a two-way street...) or look for alternative employment.

Assuming however (as above) that your job is not Time Sensitive - I would lay out to my Manager that having a flexible start time (within a reasonable time band) is something that you have had informally for the past few years, it is something that you like about your job and works for you.
Then outline that in return you either stay late or work through lunch or do whatever in order to make up the time, so that the business is still getting the full 8 hours of your time.
Ask if this arrangement can be continued in a formal capacity: e.g. you will arrive between 8:30 and 9 am, but in return will be making up time in the evening.
If your manager says no - then as above, your choice is to comply or move on.

He has been treating me differently over the last month after I voiced concerns over a lack of support from my administration. I’ve been with my employer for 6 years. This is the first time I’ve ever had an issue with being asked a question like this. In the email he mentioned specific times down to the minute as if he was looking for something. I spoke with their supervisor and voiced my concerns about this and other worrisome behavior from him and they stated that I had nothing to worry about. He just emailed me stating he heard I had a problem with his question so he wants to meet. So….

Now I'm concerned that he’s looking to start an argument or something.

With all due respect, one party here is picking a fight. And it's not your boss.

@AngelaTart - If you don’t have a problem with your supervisor’s questions your discussion shouldn’t be a problem.

@AngelaTart: You are being oversensitive. This was an entirely reasonable question. You say you gave a reasonable answer. That should be the end of it

@keshlam - It's not clear they even notified the supervisor.  The author just feels the supervisor is "obsessed" with them and treats them differently, which is a deep relationship problem between the employee and the supervisor.

@Donald: ... Which may go back to "oversensitive".

@AngelaTart you've also apparently complained about his question around the company.

Way too much overthinking - IMHO.
Uncertainty is the bain of business. Expecting team members to be on time when a department or group runs synchronously (or close to it) is important.
Even if the the department or group is async, it is reasonable for schedules to be respected.
BUT - People are people. Stuff happens. Just how often and how professionally it is handled when it does happen is the key. Communication and not trying to BS someone counts alot.
Can someone legally ask someone ask about how long it took to get to work? Please lose even considering wondering about that. That is so far away from personal responsibility to be frightening. What if you are asked about having an alarm clock, will you find a lawyer. That isn't what the labor laws are for.
